# MDX Query - How to replace null with 0 in crossjoin

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to replace nulls with 0 in a crossjoin result of a mdx query.

This is my query:

---

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS

([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[X],[Measures].[MONTANTE])

MEMBER [Measures].[Y] AS

([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[Y],[Measures].[MONTANTE])

SELECT

NON EMPTY {[Measures].[X],[Measures].[Y]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY{[Classificador Orgânico].[A].children*

[Programas e Medidas].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[B].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[C].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa Rubricas].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa Rubricas].[B].children*

[Fonte de Financiamento].[A].children} ON ROWS

FROM [Cube]

WHERE ([Calendar].[Year].&[2018],[Calendar].[Month].&[04])
```

---

I already try to use coalesceempty in the calculated members but replaces all the nulls before the NonEmptyCrossjoin (the query doesn't even answer).

The ideal solution is to replace nulls only after the NonEmptyCrossjoin .What is the proper way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Regards, Cristiana Dias

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS

([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[X],[Measures].[MONTANTE]), FORMAT_STRING = '#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;;0'

MEMBER [Measures].[Y] AS

([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[Y],[Measures].[MONTANTE]), FORMAT_STRING = '#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;;0'

SELECT

NON EMPTY {[Measures].[X],[Measures].[Y]} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY{[Classificador Orgânico].[A].children*

[Programas e Medidas].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[B].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa].[C].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa Rubricas].[A].children*

[Classificador Económico Despesa Rubricas].[B].children*

[Fonte de Financiamento].[A].children} ON ROWS

FROM [Cube]

WHERE ([Calendar].[Year].&[2018],[Calendar].[Month].&[04])
```

I have just added FORMAT_STRING. The first argument is how positive values should be formatted, the second is how negative values should be formatted, the third argument is how 0 values should be formatted, and the fourth argument is how NULL should be formatted - display a 0 instead.

The problem with using CoalesceEmpty or isEmpty like this

```
IIF(ISEMPTY(([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[X],[Measures].[MONTANTE])) , 0 , ([Indicador].[Indicador Descrição].&[X],[Measures].[MONTANTE]))
```

is that you are filling empty cells in the cube with zeros, so result set of cross join will be huge, and query probably won't finish at all.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! 
I tried with format_string, as you suggested, but I still get the nulls in the crossjoin result.

Comment: That's strange since we defined format_string for NULL for both measures. Maybe you could try to clear MDX query cash, just to be sure that you are not getting cashed results.